# Resultado do sql no spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, spring, spring-boot

Boa tarde,

Preciso de uma ajuda para fazer um endpoint no Spring Boot, no banco de dados (MySQL), eu tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT U.NOME, P.DESCRICAO FROM USUARIO_PERMISSAO UP 
    JOIN USUARIO U ON UP.ID_USUARIO = U.ID 
    JOIN PERMISSAO P ON UP.ID_PERMISSAO = P.ID
```

A tabela Usuario_Permissão, ela é criada pelo banco, ManyToMany da tabela usuário e permissão, gostaria de saber como faço um endpoint que posso trazer o resultado.

Como não tenho essa "model", não estou conseguindo fazer o retorno do repository.

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT U.NOME, P.DESCRICAO FROM USUARIO_PERMISSAO UP JOIN USUARIO U ON UP.ID_USUARIO = U.ID JOIN PERMISSAO P ON UP.ID_PERMISSAO = P.ID") 
Object findByUsuarioPermissao();

@GetMapping
public Object findUsuarioPermissao() {
    return usuarioRepository.findByUsuarioPermissao();
}
```

Porém na hora de testar está aparecendo esse erro:

```
"message": "query did not return a unique result: 20; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 20"
```

Comment: Olá, o que já tentou fazer em termos de código?

Comment: faz um favor pra gente? edita a pergunta e insere esses código ai de cima. Valeu.

Comment: De acordo com o erro essa query está retornando uma lista, tem duas maneiras de resolver, fazendo o retorno ser uma List<Object> ou colocar um LIMIT 1 na query sql. PS recormendo fazer a entity dessa tabela, fica bem mais facil trabalhar, nao sei se o Object vai funcionar pois n é serializable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é porque o método `findByUsuarioPermissao` espera o retorno de um objeto apenas e sua consulta está retornando mais de um objeto.
O ideal seria mudar para `List<Object>` ou limitar sua query para trazer apenas um resultado.